# Gradle build with AdscendMedia SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a unity project exported as an android studio project and I've added the AdscendMedia sdk to my gradle build file but now I'm getting this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

And this is my gradle build file:

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven { url "https://bitbucket.org/adscend/androidsdk/raw/master/" }
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
//  compile(name: 'appcompat-v7-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'cardview-v7-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'customtabs-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'facebook-android-wrapper-7.9.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-ads-lite-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-base-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-basement-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-clearcut-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'pollfish-googleplay-4.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-v4-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-vector-drawable-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile 'com.adscendmedia.sdk:adscendmedia:2.1.23'
    compile project(':answers')
    compile project(':beta')
    compile project(':cheetah-mobile')
    compile project(':crashlytics')
    compile project(':crashlytics-wrapper')
    compile project(':fabric')
    compile project(':fabric-init')
    compile project(':Supersonic')
    compile files('libs/adscendunity.jar')
    compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs { release {
        storeFile file('C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/KidKiwiKeyStore.keystore')
        storePassword ''
        keyAlias 'cashpal'
        keyPassword ''
    } }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}
```

When I comment the play-services-basement line then it compiles, however I need that file for my app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"play-services-basement" is a dependency of "play-services-base". If you're using basement, base will automatically be included.

Try commenting out "play-services-base" and see if the project builds.

Comment: Well I need the base and basement files, I believe I just need to edit the 'classes.jar' file inside the play-services-basement file and recompile it into the .aar. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. U need to clean your build then go step wise adding one by one  dependency, so this will help you to find cause.

   - compileSdkVersion 23
   - buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
   - minSdkVersion 15
   - targetSdkVersion 23
   - compile 'com.adscendmedia.sdk:adscendmedia:2.1.23'
     Same for support lib -
     Use all play services u mentioned are working fine

I have tested your gradle code with all dependency for me it works

Comment: I know what the error is. It's this:
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

It's a conflict between com.adscendmedia.sdk:adscendmedia:2.1.23
and play-services-basement.

Not sure how to solve it?